# AJAX Search with Table Listing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a table listing that is pulled from a mysql query. I have put a textbox and a button to take a search query. I'm not sure how to take the query and then do a backend query. Basically I want to update the table listing to match the query. What is the process to do this? I'm using codeigniter but I just need to understand how to do this with regular html/php. Some direction would be great.

I added some javascript to do a get on the button click.

```
$(function(){
$("#searchBtn").click(function(){

    $.ajax({

        url: "tablelist/searchquery/" + $('searchquery').val()

      });

   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than implement yourself, I would try on of jQuery's search plugins. Here is a good [list of them](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/14-jquery-live-search-plugins/).

Basically, you make the ajax call and in the callback update the results.

Comment: I have used #6 from that list: jQuery quicksearch plugin. It's very easy to use. 
@philfry once you use one of these plugins, you don't need to perform another back-end query since the quicksearch plugin performs a search on the table that you have already generated using a MySQL query.